December 2018 Community Moderator Election Results
Cryptography's third moderator election has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:
  
They'll be joining the existing crew shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking e-sushi who will be stepping down as moderator.
For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here, or view a summary report online.

First I'd like to join Jon in thanking e-sushi in the most appropriate way (for him) I know: With memey pictures!

Thank you for all you did, even though your destiny caught up to you:

And now please enjoy your new "freedom":


As for Maarten and Ella, I'd like to welcome you both to the mod team!


Ella,
Maarten,   

No, seriously, having known you both for some time I'm very confident you two are a perfect fit for the job. Enjoy the ride! 
May your mod journey be as adventurous and as gentle as mine. I wish you both all the best. 

As for all the kind words: thank you. (I saw what you did there @SEJPM ) 
To each and every one of you: thanks for all the head-ups, flags, help, comments, objections, discussions, and generally for putting up with me as a moderator. It may seem a bit strange to say so, but I want you to know it has all been worth it. Without each and every user in our community, my mod job wouldn't have been such a great experience… and all I can do is to humbly thank you for that.
Now, stop reading… you better go answer some questions on our main site before I start getting all sentimental here. 
o/
